# How to force bitcoind to include a specific transaction as an input of another transaction?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, doublespend, api

I would want to force bitcoind to include a specific transaction as an input of another transaction. This is so as to prevent people front wanting to launch a double-spend attack on the website. The method is similar to the one used by [SatoshiDice](http://www.satoshidice.com/bits.php). How can I accomplish this task with the standard client?

Answer (score 6):

This will be possible using the 'raw transaction interface' that was added recently and scheduled to be part of the 0.7.0 release.

With `listunspent` you can request a list of available coins sent to a particular (wallet) address, and with `createrawtransaction` you can build a transaction that consumes specified coins. Finally, `sendrawtransaction` can be used to broadcast a prepared raw transaction to the network.

Comment: Any idea of when 0.7.0 will be released?

Comment: 0.7.0rc1 was released yesterday, so... soon.